# Invalid Solidity Type Tuple[]

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a contract on the Ropsten test network and I am trying to return an array of structs but I am receiving the following error in my JS console.

[image]

I am including the following at the top of my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

and this is the function I am calling

```
 function getAllLand() external view returns (Land[]) {
        return landRegister;
    }
```

I know that this particular feature is experimental but any idea why this error might be thrown?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing issues in same contract method execution using web3js(1.0.0-beta.36). var abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"s","type":"string"},{"components":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"},{"name":"b","type":"uint256"}],"name":"b","type":"tuple"}],"name":"foo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"y","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"z","outputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"},{"name":"b","type":"u

Comment: It is found that web3js version was not correct. The issue is resolved with 1.0.0-beta.36.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error lies within the web3-object, not your smart contract. The struct feature is not yet implemented there.

See https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1241 where this issue is described.

So basically you can work with solidity-structs when interacting with your contract-functions inside a contract or with a library, but not to pass data from web3 to your contract or to retrieve data from the contract through web3.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1241 is solved and included in the release [`web3.js 1.0.0-beta.36`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.36). Now you can call Solidity functions with struct parameters.

**Example from the issue:**

**Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Test {

    struct Bar {
        uint a;
        uint b;
    }

    Bar public z;
    string public y;

    function foo(string s, Bar b) public {
        y = s;
    }

}
```

**Javascript Call**

```
contract.methods.foo("hello", [ 1, 2 ]).send({ from: '0x...' })
```