# Pass array of structs to contract from truffe using ABIEncoderV2

Tags: solidity, truffle, arrays, struct

**How do you pass an array of structs from Truffle (javascript) to a smart contract (Solidity)?**

There are a few similar questions (like [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36229/invalid-solidity-type-tuple) and [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30999/pass-array-of-structs-from-java-script)) whose answers say you cannot pass a struct to a public function in solidity or are using a version of Solidity before 4.0.19. However, I'm using ABIEncoderV2, where this is not a problem.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: invalid solidity type!: tuple[]
```

Truffle test suite:

```
const foo = artifacts.require('./FOO.sol');
it('test', async () => {
    let coordsContract = await foo.new();
    const coord0 = {x: 100, y: 200};
    const coords = [coord0];
    const worked = await coordsContract.loopCoords(coords);
    assert.isTrue(worked);
});
```

Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract FOO {
    struct Coordinates {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
    }

    function loopCoords(Coordinates[] coords) public returns (bool) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            //do stuff
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to pass javascript array `coords` to a solidity function `loopCoords`. Solidity function is not able to interpret  `coords` as an array and it is interpreting it as a mapping.

I am not sure but I think your problem is [how to pass an array as a parameter from javascript web3 to a solidity function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8362/passing-an-array-as-a-parameter-from-javascrpt-web3-to-a-solidity-function)
You need to pass an argument of `loopCoords` as the following:

```
await coordsContract.loopCoords.getData(coords)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a place where contract.method.getData(params) might be documented? I can't find how to use this method anywhere.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help you. You can refer to the following blog https://medium.com/@k3no/ethereum-tokens-smart-contracts-743b8b634e7a. Apart from this, I didn't get any documentation for getData method